# Is there a module for python that does facial recognition?

Tags: python, image-recognition

Is there a module for python that does facial recognition? It should take in an image and compare it to a different image.

Comment: As Far I know you can do facial recognition and training using the built in libraries in Opencv, it offer object tracking too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) :) it is a useful toolkit for this sort of thing and is implemented in Python, C, and C++.

It also has some pretty thorough documentation from what I remember.

Comment: yes OpenCV is the first thing that popped up in my mind, but was too slow to respond. great how it's available in several languages, like as in XCode test skeleton project on my MBP.

Answer (score 6):

@William beat me to it, but here are a couple blogs making reference to OpenCV with some Python code.

- [Face recognition – much easier than expected](http://benosteen.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/face-recognition-much-easier-than-expected/)
- [Face Detection in Static Images with Python](http://creatingwithcode.com/howto/face-detection-in-static-images-with-python/)

They are the top hits in Google when searching "python module facial recognition." Hope it helps.

Comment: The two links are both about detection not recognition.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not debating the answers given but just wanted to point out that OpenCV isn't the only option, for example, pyfaces is a eigenface based approach / library designed specifically for facial matching. SimpleCV is new to the scene as well and from what I understand it can be used for face detection and recognition though SimpleCV isn't as powerful or as stable as OpenCV yet but just wanted to point out other options worth exploring.

- http://code.google.com/p/pyfaces/
- http://pyfaces.blogspot.com/

Comment: Good, but seemingly old (from 2010). Do you have any updates on Python modules for face comparison (matching some new face with the existing faces to retrieve the information about the person on the image / video)?